# Facebook ads 1487478 error: “Invalid Geo Locations”

Tags: python, facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

I'm running into an "Invalid Geo Locations" error when creating an adgroup through Facebook Ads API. I'm using the Python SDK. Here is what I'm sending in the body:

```
campaign_group_id=xxxxxxx&targeting={"geo_locations":{"custom_locations":[{"distance_unit":"kilometer","latitude":35.933333,"longitude":0.083333,"radius":50}]},"interests":[{"id":"6003252179711","name":"Engineering"}]}&name=My Adset&bid_info={"ACTIONS":50}&end_time=4/20/2015&bid_type=CPA&campaign_status=ACTIVE&daily_budget=100
```

And here is the message I get from the API:

```
{u'is_transient': False, u'error_subcode': 1487478, u'error_user_title': u'Invalid Geo Locations', u'error_data': {u'blame_field': u'targeting'}, u'error_user_msg': u'Invalid Geo Locations', u'code': 100, u'message': u'Invalid parameter', u'type': u'FacebookApiException'}
```

I don't see what's wrong with my targeting spec. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: When I try this custom location in an adset post via curl my error response is: {"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"FacebookApiException","code":100,"error_data":{"blame_field":"targeting"},"error_subcode":1488030,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Radius too small","error_user_msg":"There are too few users living within this radius. Please choose a larger radius."}} Do you get similar via raw curl request?

Comment: no, still getting the same. That's strange because according to [FB specs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs/v2.3):
_The limits of the radius are 0.62 to 50 miles, or 1 to 80 kilometers._

Comment: How sure are you that there are enough FB users within 50km of that location who also are in the Engineering interest?

Comment: I'm not sure of anything :s but how would I know that? I'm doing it programmatically (it's 50km radius for every location). Is there somewhere in the API doc that says: "You targeting will be rejected in case there are not enough FB users." ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error posted by bjeavons shows, there needs to be a certain minimal people in your targeting. If your targeting audience is too small, for example a specific interest in a too small/little populated area, you can't create the targeting.

I performed the following call (note the API version and that bid info and targeting are now required on Ad Set level instead)

```
curl -v \
  -F 'campaign_group_id=<adcampaign_id>' \
  -F 'targeting={"geo_locations":{"custom_locations":[{"distance_unit":"kilometer","latitude":35.933333,"longitude":0.083333,"radius":50}]},"interests":[{"id":"6003252179711","name":"Engineering"}]}' \
  -F 'name=My Adset' \
  -F 'bid_info={"ACTIONS":50}' \
  -F 'end_time=4/20/2015' \
  -F 'bid_type=CPA' \
  -F 'campaign_status=PAUSED' \
  -F 'daily_budget=100' \
  -F 'access_token=<access_token>' \
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/<ac_id>/adcampaigns
```

For me this returns:

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"FacebookApiException","code":100,"error_data":{"blame_field":"targeting"},"error_subcode":1488030,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Radius too small","error_user_msg":"There are too few users living within this radius. Please choose a larger radius."}}
```

which is the same error as bjeavons. I would suggest using other interests to broaden your audience. It is documented that some audience types require at least 20 people.

Answer (score 0):

Expand the radious of all addresses to at least 15mi.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).